Divisors sum and Bessel Function related sums
Discovered the following relation:
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \sigma (k) \left(K_2\left(4 \pi  \sqrt{k+y} \sqrt{y}\right)-K_0\left(4 \pi  \sqrt{k+y} \sqrt{y}\right)\right)=\frac{\pi  K_1(4 \pi  y)-3 K_0(4 \pi  y)}{48 \pi ^2 y}$$
where $\sigma(x)$ is a divisors sum, $K_n(x)$ is Modified Bessel function of second kind and $y>0$.
Also each of sums
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \sigma (k) K_2\left(4 \pi  \sqrt{k+y} \sqrt{y}\right)$$
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \sigma (k) K_0\left(4 \pi  \sqrt{k+y} \sqrt{y}\right)$$
converge.
The question here is: as the difference (the first sum) has a closed form, may we expect each of sums above to have the closed form either, and if so does someone know what it can be?

In order to partially satisfy @Greg Martin request let me just provide numerical examples which will show the correctness of first relation. As I don't know any simple way of proving it.
For $y=1$
$$\sum _{k=1}^{300} \sigma (k) \left(K_2\left(4 \pi  \sqrt{k+1} \sqrt{1}\right)-K_0\left(4 \pi  \sqrt{k+1} \sqrt{1}\right)\right) = 6.8126525731073335538349556626598125635572137980741872738568342124.10^{-10}$$
$$\frac{\pi  K_1(4 \pi)-3 K_0(4 \pi)}{48 \pi ^2} = 6.8126525731073335538349556626598125635572137980741872738568342124.10^{-10}$$
For $y=0.2$
$$\sum _{k=1}^{300} \sigma (k) \left(K_2\left(4 \pi  \sqrt{k+0.2} \sqrt{0.2}\right)-K_0\left(4 \pi  \sqrt{k+0.2} \sqrt{0.2}\right)\right) = 0.000466622676964315708526403991580236142341156773881429672591795$$
$$\frac{\pi  K_1(4 \pi 0.2)-3 K_0(4 \pi 0.2)}{48 \pi ^2 0.2} = 0.000466622676964315708526403991580236142344783982506129849211143$$

There is a promissive relation to Ramanujan's work.
Found another paper related to Hardy's work.

It feels like it would make sense to give some indication of why the first identity is true, if you want people to think about the question being asked.

Actually I don't know a simple way of proving it. :( So this is why trying to come frome the other end.

What evidence do you have that it's true?

I believe your sum simplifies to $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \sigma(k) \left(K_2\left(4 \pi \sqrt{k+y} \sqrt{y}\right)-K_0\left(4 \pi \sqrt{k+y} \sqrt{y}\right)\right)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \sigma(k) \frac{K_1\left(4 \pi \sqrt{y} \sqrt{k+y}\right)}{2 \pi \sqrt{y} \sqrt{k+y}}.$$

Actually these are equivalent sums, but in reality I think we have exact formula for the $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \sigma(k) K_n\left(4 \pi \sqrt{k+y} \sqrt{y}\right)$$

@KStarGamer Could you please give a formula number for the OP identity in your linked paper?

Mathematica gives the Mellin transform $$\mathcal{M}_y\left\frac{\pi  K_1(4 \pi  y)-3 K_0(4 \pi  y)}{48 \pi ^2 y}\right=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\pi  K_1(4 \pi  y)-3 K_0(4 \pi  y)}{48 \pi ^2 y} y^{s-1} , dy=\frac{1}{3} 2^{-s-5} \pi ^{-s-1} \left(\pi, \Gamma \left(\frac{s}{2}-1\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{s}{2}\right)-3, \Gamma \left(\frac{s-1}{2}\right)^2\right),\quad\Re(s)>2$$ which has no $\zeta(s)$ term so I'm not sure how this ties into the Dirichlet divisor problem.

@KStarGamer this is really interesting paper. But I also was unable to find the result and also I proved it in a very different way. So if the identity is in this paper, would be very nice if there is the same result proved in another way.

What do you think should I create an article about this formula, is it something that may be interesting for others?
